# Mongoose: Populating nested property and querying at the same time

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Website schema:

```
let websiteSchema = new Schema({
  url: { type: string }
});
```

Post subschema:

```
let postSchema = new Schema({
  website: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Website' },
  message: { type: String }
});
```

User schema:

```
let userSchema = new Schema({
  posts: [postSchema]
});
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Let's say I want to populate all of User 123123's websites. This works.

```
User
    .findById(ObjectId(123123))
    .populate({ path: 'posts.website', model: 'Website' });
```

But how do I populate only the websites with the URL 'google.com'? This correctly populates the `website` property for posts in the `posts` array that have the URL 'google.com', but it also returns all the unpopulated posts as well:

```
User
    .findById(ObjectId(123123))
    .populate({
        path: 'posts.website',
        model: 'Website',
        match: { 'url': 'google.com' }
    });
```

Is there a way to filter out the posts with unpopulated (null) websites?

Comment: Can you try `match: { 'website.url': 'google.com' }` ?

Comment: You can not get required result using mongodb query. You have to do manual filtering after getting result.

Comment: @Chinni `match: { 'website.url': 'google.com' }` will return an empty array. I am currently just manually filtering out the unpopulated entries but was just wondering if there's a better way than doing that.